# How long is "living" time for files in apache's tmp folder

Tags: php, apache, file, tmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php:: how long to tmp files stay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653224/php-how-long-to-tmp-files-stay)

After uploading file on server, his location is tmp folder right?

My question is: If We dont removing file from tmp folder, how long time will this file in tmp folder? As I know server automatically removes all files from tmp folder, right?

Answer (score 1):

> After uploading file on server, his location is tmp folder right?

Not necessarily; Apache does not itself save uploaded content anywhere.

If you are using PHP, uploaded files are removed from the upload temporary directory immediately when the request is completed.

Comment: `Not necessarily; Apache does not itself save uploaded content anywhere.`

But, before we copyng file using function `move_uploaded_file()`, file location, as default is tmp folder, right?

Comment: PHP is what puts the file there, not Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is depends by your configuration. If you set a custom temporary folder for uploaded files in `php.ini` or in your application, it won't automatically removed by system. By default, php uses `/tmp` directory for temporary files. It's not related with apache.

On a linux system `/tmp` (or `/var/tmp`) is designed to use with files which are created, edited and deleted in a short period of time.

If you don't remove your files in /tmp, your server would automatically remove many of them (or all) on next system reboot.