# PHP: How to change the default time before an uploaded file gets deleted from the default tmp folder?

Tags: php

I'm wondering about how to change the default amount of time before deleting the uploaded files in tmp folder in php.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is effectively answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653224/php-how-long-to-tmp-files-stay. You can't change temporary file lifetimes; you just need to move them somewhere else. "The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed." Different OSs may handle temp files differently.

Comment: The temp file lives for the lifetime of the script it was uploaded to. There is no "time limit" beyond that.

Comment: Thanks to you both :)