# Keeping uploaded files with their tmp name

Tags: php

Is it a good practice to keep an uploaded file with it's *tmp_name*? Check the following example:

```
$short_tmp_name = substr($_FILES['tmp_name'], -6)
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file'], "$uploads_dir/$short_tmp_name");
```

When handling file uploading like in above example:

1. Will name collisions happen?
2. Does this practice reveal any security issues?

---

**EDIT:**

I've clarified the question(modified the code example).

Comment: You probably won't be able to save/retrieve the temp file's name as PHP automatically deletes those when the upload process is done. Plus, you have a typo in `$_FILES('tmp_name')`.

Comment: There are not particulars security issues, and naming collision his almost impossible. BTW, is good practice ever check if the file already exists in the destination directory to avoid unattended results.

Comment: @Fred-ii- He move the file after uploaded, then the file will not be deleted

Comment: @fusion3k I said the *temp* files (*"...the temp file's name..."*). Read my comment again and read http://stackoverflow.com/a/4653233/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4653406/ and http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: **Please also note** that in `$_FILES[file]['tmp_name']` is not stored the fiename **but the absolute filepath**

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know-it. I repeat: the OP move the tempfile to a new location, so the file not will be deleted. Maybe I don't be clear, i'm sorry

Comment: @fusion3k Read *their* question again, this part in particular: *"Is it a good practice to keep an uploaded file with it's tmp_name?"* < operative words here.

Comment: Alexander, your question is unclear. By what I can tell from what you've written *"Is it a good practice to keep an uploaded file with it's tmp_name?"* - You can't retrieve that temp file name, since you don't know what the file name will be in the first place so you won't be able to save/retrieve it because it's random and you can't retrieve what you don't know. The manual states that they are automatically deleted as soon as the upload process is done. You're going to need to clarify/elaborate on your question as this is turning out to be a *"argue amongst ourselves"* type of question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- don't be touchy: the question is clear, the OP move the file and he intends `tmp_name` as name, not as filepath. peace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no issue as such,  but to be on safer side and handle error,  do something like shown below. NOTE : Just a sample code, add more error/other checks and handling based on your need

```
$error = '';

if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] == 0) {
    $error = 'Uploading failed';
} 
else if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > MAX_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE) {
    $error = 'File size exceeds ' . MAX_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE_MB;
} 
else if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    $error = 'Error while uploading';
}

if(!$error) {
    $file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

    if (file_exists(DESTINATION . $file_name))  {
        $path_parts = pathinfo($dstFile . $file_name);
        $file_name = $path_parts['filename'] . '-' . time() . '.' . $path_parts['extension'];
    }

    $dstFile = DESTINATION . $file_name;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$dstFile)) {
        //its done
    }
    else {
        $error = 'Unexpected system error';
    }
}
```